# How can I change the fill color or hide other continent which is not selected onRegionClick in jvectormap

Tags: jvectormap

I already handle onHover event for example when I hover any country on Asia all asia country will be red. All I want to do is when I click Country in Asia it will focus on asia and hide or change color other continents. Is it possible to do this ? Any Idea guys? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set focus on a certain region, there is a handy method called `setFocus()`. The [jVectorMap documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/) goes into detail about this. The parameter here is your region code.

```
map.setFocus('India');
```

If you wanted to change the color of unselected regions, you could compare the list of those selected with a list of those that aren't and build an array to set on the map. This should at least point you in the right direction. Your implementation may differ.

```
var allRegions = map.regions;
var selectedRegions = map.getSelectedRegions();
var unselectedColor = '#4E7387';
var unselectedRegions = new Array();

for (var i in allRegions) {
    var isSelected = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < selectedRegions.length; j++) {
        if (i == selectedRegions[j])
            isSelected = true;
    }
    if (!isSelected)
        unselectedRegions[i] = unselectedColor;
}
map.series.regions[0].setValues(unselectedRegions);
```